# php mail send form question?

Tags: php, forms

Wondering if anyone know how to automatically send the user an email after he/she fills out a form. I have the form emailed to me after it gets submitted, but I can't figure out how to capture the user's email from the form field and have it send it to them automatically???

Here is some code that I use to send the mail:

```
  //mail the message before redirecting
if($_POST['dosend'] == "yes"){

// The message
$headers = "From: no-reply@domain.com";

$message = "NEW Message :: ".$_POST['event_name']." \n Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n Click link to http://www.domain.com/admin/ Approve this Event!";

// Send
mail('me@me.com', 'New :: Calendar Message', $message, $headers);
}
  //end mail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve it from one of the `$_POST` variables:

```
// HTML
<input type="text" name="email" />

// PHP (you might want to check if it's valid too)
$user_email = $_POST['email'];

mail($user_email, 'New :: Calendar Message', $message, $headers);
```

You can also add yourself as BCC, so you only have to call the `mail()` function once:

```
$headers = "From: no-reply@domain.com \n" .
           "Bcc: You \n";

mail($user_email, 'New :: Calendar Message', $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Wicked. Thanks dude! I will try it out now!

Answer (score 0):

it should be in one of the post fields if the user put it in the form.